# findViewById() doesn't find RecyclerView in a second activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a MainActivity with a RecyclerView (trackingsRecycler) and an Adapter to list a CardView and it works fine.

When I click on some cardview, the app calls (with Intent) another activity (DetailsActivity) and it should list another RecyclerView (detailsRecycler).

but in DetailsActivity the code

```
RecyclerView detailsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_details_view);
```

doesn't work

the findViewById returns 'null'

Can anyone help me?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TRACKING = "com.example.cooltracker.MESSAGE";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TrackingsAdapter adapter;
private List<Tracking> trackingList;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String webserviceURL;
private TextView total;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webserviceURL = "http://myWebServiceUrl.com/params";

    ---> recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_main_view); <--- Ok!!

    trackingList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter      = new TrackingsAdapter(this, trackingList);

    total = findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(1, dpToPx(5), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
```

## On TrackingsAdapter.java I put the clickListener to call the next screen

```
public class TrackingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackingsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

      private Context mContext;
      private List<Tracking> trackingList;

      public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {...}

      @override
      public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { 
             View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tracking_card, parente, attachToRoot:false);
             final MyViewHolder mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);

             return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder...){
             ...
             ...
             ...

             //Here I set the click listener
             holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                    getDetails(tracking.getTrack());
             }
       });

       private void getDetails(String tracking){

               //Call next screen DetailsActivity...
               Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);

               intent.putExtra(TRACKING, tracking);

               mContext.startActivity(intent);
       }
```

So far it's working well!!! The code calls the next screen...

But...

## On the next screen should also have a list view (RecyclerView)

DetailsActivity.java

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DetailsAdapter adapter;
    private List<Tracking> detailList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String webserviceURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

          //get intent
          Intent intent = getIntent();

          String tracking  = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TRACKING);

          //set string in layout
          TextView tvHeaderLine1 = findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderLine1);
          tvHeaderLine1.setText(tracking);

          webserviceURL = "http://werService.com/otherAction";


          //THIS PART IS NOT WORKING ///
          ----> recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_detail_view); <----
          System.out.println(recyclerView); // It's always returning NULL

          detailList   = new ArrayList<>();
          adapter      = new DetailsAdapter(this, detailList);

          RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
          //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
          //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

          // prepare the loading Dialog
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
          pDialog.setMessage("Message");
          pDialog.setCancelable(false);


          ...
          ...

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have something called `recycler_details_view` in your *DetailsActivity* layout? Moreover, shouldn't `findViewById(...)` be preceded by the correct type cast (i.e.: `(RecyclerView) ...`)?

Comment: Can you post your code here

Comment: Add a [mcve], please

Comment: @KlingKlang The problem was related to this.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

First I thought... if I'm using a recycler, why do I need two?? I shoud use the same... So I set

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

on the DetailsActivity.class and I used the same... Thanks!!!

I'll improve the design now...

The screens are here... I need at least 10 reputation to post images... =/

[MainActivity Screen](http://cooltracker.com.br/img/app/MainActivity.jpg)

[DetailsActivity Screen](http://cooltracker.com.br/img/app/DetailsActivity.jpg)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

When findViewById returns null, it means it couldn't find a view with the specified Id inside the layout you set in the call to setContentView().

So, basically the layout you're passing in the setContentView() method, doesn't have a view with the "recycler_details_view" Id.